# JFrame doesn't dispose()

Tags: java

So, I have a login JFrame which shows up when I run the code. The problem is if the user enters the correct userName and password this login frame needs to be disposed when the other frame is shown up but it doesn't. I tried `dispose()`, `setVisible = false`, but still no chance to be hidden or disposed.

```
 class LoggingWindow extends JFrame {


  static JFrame loginFrame = new JFrame();   
  JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
  JTextField loginNameFld = new JTextField(10);
  JPasswordField loginPassFld = new JPasswordField(10);
  JTextField statusFld = new JTextField(11);
  String userName = "user";
  String password = "password";

  //Initialize loginFrame 

   public static void initLoginFrame() {     
    JFrame loginWindow = new LoggingWindow();
    //loginFrame.setTitle("\"Moflo Registration\"");
    loginWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    loginWindow.setResizable(false);
    loginWindow.setUndecorated(true);
    loginWindow.setVisible(true);
    loginWindow.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
    loginWindow.setSize(new Dimension(220, 290));
    loginWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    loginWindow.pack();

   LoggingWindow() {

        loginFrame.add(loginPanel);
        loginPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbb = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbb.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        gbb.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;


        JPanel loginNameAndPasswordPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.add(loginNameAndPasswordPanel,gbb);
        gbb.gridx = 0;
        gbb.gridy = 2;


        loginNameAndPasswordPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

        JLabel loginNameLab = new JLabel("Нэр :           ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        loginNameAndPasswordPanel.add(loginNameLab, gbc);

        JLabel loginPassLab = new JLabel("Нууц үг :     ");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        loginNameAndPasswordPanel.add(loginPassLab, gbc);

        loginNameFld.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        loginNameAndPasswordPanel.add(loginNameFld, gbc);

        loginPassFld.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        loginNameAndPasswordPanel.add(loginPassFld, gbc);

        statusFld.setEditable(false);

        loginNameAndPasswordPanel.add(statusFld, gbc);
        statusFld.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        loginPanel.add(buttonsPanel,gbb);
        gbb.gridx = 0;
        gbb.gridy = 3;  
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gba = new GridBagConstraints();
        gba.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        gba.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

        JButton loginBtn = new JButton("Нэвтрэх");
        gba.gridx = 0;
        gba.gridy = 0;
        buttonsPanel.add(loginBtn, gba);     

        loginBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        String name = loginNameFld.getText();
        String pass = loginPassFld.getText();

    if(event.getSource() == loginBtn){
    if (name.equals(userName) && pass.equals(password)) {
                  initMainFrame();
                  loginFrame.dispose(); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Системд нэвтэрлээ. Өнөөдөр " + showDate, " ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } else {
        statusFld.setText("Нэр эсвэл нууц үг буруу байна.");
    }

        }
        }
    }); 

        JButton closeBtn = new JButton("       Хаах    ");
        gba.gridx = 1;
        gba.gridy = 0;
        buttonsPanel.add(closeBtn, gba);
        add(loginPanel);
        closeBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }); 
}
            //Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

       initLoginFrame();
     }
    });
   }
  }

  public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

 //Initialzie mainFrame
public static void initMainFrame() {
    JFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();


    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    mainFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

some, i think unimportant statements are not shown for the sake of brevity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you confused "loginWindow" with "loginFrame".  You try to use

```
loginFrame.dispose();
```

but your content is on loginWindow, not loginFrame.

I was able to get it to dispose the username window doing the following.

```
static JFrame loginWindow;  <--- create as class variable, not local.
//loginFrame.add(loginPanel);  <--- doesn't appear that this is actually used

if(event.getSource() == loginBtn){
                    if (name.equals(userName) && pass.equals(password)) {
                        MainFrame.initMainFrame();
                        //loginFrame.dispose();    <--- again, not used
                        loginWindow.dispose();     <--- want to dispose
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Системд нэвтэрлээ. Өнөөдөр " , " ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    } else {
                        statusFld.setText("Нэр эсвэл нууц үг буруу байна.");
                    }

                }
```

You must also change this:

```
JFrame loginWindow = new LoggingWindow();
```

to:

```
 loginWindow = new LoggingWindow();
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for replying. Yes, I definitely confused with loginFrame was indeed useless. I created a class variable: static JFrame loginWindow; as you told but it makes a NullPointer exception.

Comment: Hello glad to help.  you must also change JFrame loginWindow = new LoggingWindow(); to loginWindow = new LoggingWindow();  If you didn't you will get null pointer exception.  This is because  you would have 2 variables called loginWindow, one local, one class, and the class variable was never used.

Answer (score 0):

You can always dispatch the "close" event to the JFrame object:

```
loginFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(loginFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely confused with loginFrame was indeed useless. I created a class variable: static JFrame loginWindow; but it results NullPointerException.